# How to completely reload view?

Tags: ios, swift, refresh

I know in IOS you can set a view to be redrawn with this:

```
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

However, is there anyway to refresh the view in such a way that it recalls `viewDidLoad()` and all its constructor methods again?

Comment: I would suggest that you structure your view controller so that you do not *need* `viewDidLoad` to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardName", bundle:nil)

let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExampleIdentifier") as! ExampleViewController
```

And then inside whatever function:

```
window!.rootViewController = viewController
window!.makeKeyWindow()
```

This will basically reload/redraw the window. You should not try to directly call `viewDidLoad()`